# How to import random seed in cycle to obtain the same result in anytime?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to get the same results in any iteration. I tried to use `random.seed()` in my script, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

My script:

```
import statistics

Oddr=[]
Oddr_fem=[]
Oddr_mal=[]

chi = []
chi_fem=[]
chi_mal=[]


for k in range(100):
    random.seed(10)
    result = []
    exclude_hlthy = []
    for i in set(sick['predicted_age']):
        sick_ppl = sick.index[sick['predicted_age'] == i].tolist()
        L_sick = len(sick_ppl)
        if L_sick == 0:
            continue
        hlth_peers = healthy[healthy.predicted_age == i]
        L_healthy = hlth_peers.shape[0]
        if L_healthy < len(sick_ppl):
            pass
        else:
            hlthy_subsample = list(np.random.choice([x for x in hlth_peers.index if not x in exclude_hlthy], 
                                                    L_sick, replace = False))
            exclude_hlthy += hlthy_subsample
            result += hlthy_subsample
        table_ready = healthy.loc[result]
        whole_table = table_ready.append(sick, ignore_index=False)
        cross_tab = pd.crosstab(index=whole_table['dc013'], columns=whole_table['rate_aging'])
        oddsratio=(cross_tab[1][1]*cross_tab[0][0])/(cross_tab[1][0]*cross_tab[0][1])
        #Oddr += oddsratio
        Oddr.append(oddsratio)
```

In this script I got several random tables `whole_table` from one subsample.

Comment: there are several random seeds. The `numpy` one should be set using `np.random.seed(value)`. Not sure what `random` you have imported when you call `random.seed(10)` at the first line in your loop.

Comment: @PierreD Thank you! I chaged on ```np.random.seed()``` and it works now

Answer (score 0):

For every iteration you're creating a new `random.seed(10)` so try to put this line of code out of the for cycle and then should work